# I bought lean ux and ux for lean startups. The diagrams in both books are similar. What is the software used to generate the diagrams?

Tags: tools, diagramming

I bought Lean UX and UX for Lean Startups.

I noticed that both books are using the same type of software to generate their diagrams.

This one is from UX for Lean Startups.

[image]

This one is from Lean UX.

[image]

**What is this software that they are using?**

Also [cross-posted the question at quora](http://www.quora.com/User-Experience/I-bought-lean-ux-and-ux-for-lean-startups-The-diagrams-in-both-books-are-similar-What-is-the-software-used-to-generate-the-diagrams) to elicit more responses.

Comment: Have you tried asking the authors? They normally have contact information somewhere in the literature.

Comment: @FacebookAnswers Good idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They could have been built with pretty much anything.

The reason for them looking the same is that both books are in the same series by the same publisher. Having some level of visual design continuity would seem sensible.